# Understanding the SAS hash object Keysum argument

Tags: sas

Browsing the [SAS Hash Object Declare Statement Doc](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lecompobjref&docsetTarget=p00ilfw5pzcjvtn1nfya9863fozd.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n0i8i0n0noe9k3n18eirvle5wp36) I can read the following about the rarely used Keysum argument: It *"specifies the name of a variable that tracks the key summary for all keys. A key summary is a count of how many times a key has been referenced on a FIND method call."*

However, playing around with it, this seems to be a bit off. Consider the small example below. If the doc was accurate, Keysum would equal 2 (2*find() method call) in the test data set. However, it is equal to 10.

```
data _null_;
   declare hash h (suminc : 's', keysum : 'keysum');
   h.definekey ('k');
   h.definedone ();

   k = 1;
   s = 2;
   keysum = 0;

   h.add ();
   h.ref ();
   h.ref ();

   h.find ();
   h.find ();

   h.output (dataset : 'test');
run;
```

Here is my own interpretation. The variable specified in the Keysum Argument Tag is incremented by the value of the suminc variable each time the key is referenced by either an Add(), Ref() or Find() Method. At least one find() method calls must be present for the increment to take place though. Otherwise, Keysum does not increment (take out the two find() method calls above and verify).

My interpretation is from simply playing around with the code above..

So, which is more off, my interpretation or the Documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help entry ["Maintaining Key Summaries"](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=n1b4cbtmb049xtn1vh9x4waiioz4.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n145x2os6zo07kn1lr0wpgv7nxsr) explains the concept better than other parts of the documentation. My **bold**

> This SUMINC tag instructs the hash object to allocate internal storage for maintaining a summary value for each key.
>
> The summary value of a hash key is **initialized** to the value of the SUMINC variable whenever the ADD or REPLACE method is used.
>
> The summary value of a hash key is **incremented** by the value of the SUMINC variable whenever the FIND, CHECK, or REF method is used.
>
> Note that the SUMINC variable can be negative, positive, or zero valued. The variable does not need to be an integer. The SUMINC value for a key is zero by default.

I not sure why the normally near flawless documentation team is not on top of the other incomplete or imprecise statements regarding SUMINC.

The documentation example code is pretty Mickey Mouse, and better SUMINC examples would be:

- using hash to compute a weighted frequency table (Output data set has freq as keysum)
- calculating a running total in a ledger statement. (Retrieve sum with `.SUM()`)
- outputting the total of linked financial transactions (Output data set has total as keysum)

Answer (score 0):

@Richard, thank you.

Do you agree that for the initiation part, the Ref() Method initializes the value of Keysum as well? See the code below.

```
data _null_;
   declare hash h (suminc : 's', keysum : 'keysum');
   h.definekey ('k');
   h.definedone ();

   k = 1;
   s = 2;
   keysum = 0;

   h.ref ();

   h.find ();
   h.find ();

   h.output (dataset : 'test');
run;
```

Furthermore, am I correct that a Find() Method must be present for the Keysum to be initialized and incremented at all? For example, Keysum=0 in the output data set below

```
data _null_;
   declare hash h (suminc : 's', keysum : 'keysum');
   h.definekey ('k');
   h.definedone ();

   k = 1;
   s = 2;
   keysum = 0;

   h.add ();

   h.output (dataset : 'test');
run;
```

Also, I agree, stepping up the complexity of the examples in the Doc would be nice.

Comment: #1 Yes. From [HASH Language Elements](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lecompobjref&docsetTarget=p1kad1rc31k0o4n1iyzyvaz3kzwy.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) with `.REF` "you consolidate CHECK and ADD methods into a single REF method" ... "The REF method is useful for counting the number of occurrences of each key in a hash object. The REF method initializes the key summary for each key on the first ADD, and then changes the ADD for each subsequent CHECK." -- poorly worded but somewhat clear. The *changes the ADD* should probably be changed to *changes the key summary*

Comment: #2 Yes. But behavior is unexpected because a step with only `add` has the correct internal sum.  `...   h.add (); h.sum(sum:x); put x=; ... ` logs `x=2`.  So why would output data set have keysum=0 ?